# Is there a way to use $query in closures with a model method?

Tags: php, laravel

When I was working with Eager Loading. Suppose the logic inside my closure is too big and I want to convert it to a separate method. I am stuck at $query. Can you help me?

My Code

```
    ->with(['post'      => function ($query) {
           $query->whereNotNull('id');
    }]
```

I want:

```
    private function modelMethod($query){
           return $query->whereNotNull('id');
    }

    ->with(['post'      => $this->modelMethod($query)]
```

**Update 1: I had a solution but didn't look very elegant**

```
        private function modelMethod($query){
               return $query->whereNotNull('id');
        }


        $that = $this;

        ->with(['post'      => function($query) use($that){
               $that->modelMethod($query);
        }]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use  [Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes)

Prepend your desired function name with `scope`

```
public function scopeIdNotNull($query)
{
    return $query->whereNotNull('id');
}
```

Then use it like

```
->with(['post' => function ($q) {
    $q->idNotNull();
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you already received an answer, but I want to understand what was the issue in the first place. So I tried this:

```
private function modelMethod($query)
{
    return $query->where('completed', true);
}

public function testEager()
{
    return User::with(['tasks' => function($query) {
        return $this->modelMethod($query);
    }])->get();
}

$user = Auth::user();
$user->testEager(); // works
```

Could you please explain what am I missing here?

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I want. I did't really understand the $this in the closure